# Attempt to install Magento 2 Stripe Payment module manually caused white screen

Tags: xampp, stripe-payments, magento2

I followed the steps to install Stripe manually/with composer, found here:

[Stripe Magento Module](https://stripe.com/docs/plugins/magento/install)

After following all the steps, all that it has resulted in is a white screen, leaving me unable to access the backend to check if it's even installed properly.

My Magento 2.3.0 is installed on xampp, and checking through the file system, everything seems to have integrated properly, but I can't find a reason for it to have done this.

Comment: have you run all commands which is suggested by Stripe Module? Please give proper permission for your var,pub and generated folder

Comment: I followed the commands exactly. I am unsure about permissions. However, the website displayed fine before the attempt to add stripe to magento.

Comment: change local.simple.xml to local.xml in pub/errors/ folder and then you can find which error in your website

Answer (score 0):

To debug what might be the issue you should enable developer mode via command line using below commands which might provide some hints about the issue

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Also you should enable php display errors in `app/bootstrap.php` by un-commenting below line

```
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: I was in developer mode at the time of install, and the display error line was already uncommented.

Comment: Check for any error hint in log files inside var/log and apache/mysql logs as well.